# Graphical/Browser-Based PHP Unit Testing Suite?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Web interface” to PHPUnit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424457/web-interface-to-phpunit-tests)

Are there any PHP unit testing systems that have a browser-based graphical interface to run the tests in (similar to this : http://view.jquery.com/tags/1.3.2/test/)?

All the unit test options I have looked at allow you to run them from the command line but have not seen any (or could not find documentation on how to) that allow you to somehow run them from the browser.  I ask because I don't have access to the command line on the server I would need to run unit tests from.

**Update:**

In the end I decided to stick with PHPUnit.  SimpleTest does have what I was looking for but PHPUnit is the defacto standard in PHP unit testing.  I end up switching IDE from PhpED to PhpStorm and PhpStorm has a nice feature of being about to display PHPUnit test results that run on a remote server like ReSharper does for C#/Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleTest does that:

http://www.simpletest.org/en/first_test_tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it, but maybe you should try this:
http://mattmueller.me/blog/phpunit-test-report-unit-testing-in-the-browser

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a bit difficult, since the browser is not able to run php natively, I would guess that there would be a php page that would trigger the running of the tests and return an html with the results.

I would suggest you run your tests locally and if you want to get even higher fidelity setup a server/virtual machine that very closely resembles the setup you have in your production server, but that grant's you access to the console and use it as your continuos integration server.