# Simple PHP unit tester with web report and good documentation?

Tags: php, unit-testing, tdd

Is there a decent PHP unit testing framework that display the test report as a webpage and has current documentation. SimpleTest's documentation isn't reliable. Even the "Getting Started" page has errors.

I would like a simple alternative to PHPUnit that allows you to just get started writing tests quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Funnily enough, yours is a combination of two questions I asked some time ago :)

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408860/whats-the-state-of-php-unit-testing-frameworks-in-2010 in which I lamented the complicatedness of PHPUnit, but saw the light and understood that it simply is the most serious product in PHP unit testing, and probably the most worth getting into
- and ["Web interface" to PHPUnit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424457/web-interface-to-phpunit-tests) in which I was shown some really nice graphical "frontends" to PHPUnit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Enhance PHP has web-bases results and is very simple to install and use. It also has good documentation at http://www.enahance-php.com/

It is currently being actively developed to compete with other frameworks - it is downloadable for free from the website.