# Generate PHPUnit Report(Failed and Passed Tests)

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit, report

I would like to know how to generate a phpunit report which tells what tests failed and what tests passed. Any configuration in the phpunit.xml? I couldn't find any information than php coverage report.

I would something like the image below (generated by junit)

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create pretty much every output format you want from the the junit.xml logfile. An example for doing it yourself can be found [**`here`**](http://web.archive.org/web/20130402143958/http://edorian.posterous.com/creating-your-custom-phpunit-output-formats), [**`here is a table`**](http://web.archive.org/web/20110321101046/http://parthpatil.com:80/2008/05/14/formatting-phpunit-test-results-as-html-table/) and [**`here is a little more on the subject`**](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/visualizing-phpunit-runs.htm).

If you want something small for multi project there is "sismo", a very minimal CI server that runs all of your local projects so that you always know their status. [**`Check the symfony project page for details`**](http://ci.symfony-project.org/)

Usually, as most people don't need/want this reporting locally and want to see a little more, this isn't done locally and [**`a full blown Continuous Integration server like Jenkins`**](http://jenkins-php.org/) is used [**`Demo`**](http://ci.jenkins-ci.org/view/All/). It can show you all the information that `PHPUnit` can provide and much more. [**`Check my setup guide`**](http://edorian.posterous.com/setting-up-jenkins-for-php-projects) to see that installation isn't hard.

---

Update:

Also see: [SO: Web interface to phpunittests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424457/web-interface-to-phpunit-tests) and from there the [**`Visual PHPUnit`**](https://github.com/NSinopoli/VisualPHPUnit)  tool.

Comment: That is a nice collection of 404. Please post some code instead of only links.