# NetBeans : phpUNit or SimpleTest?

Tags: php, unit-testing, netbeans, phpunit, simpletest

Which one goes better with Netbeans: PHPUnit or SimpleTest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For my general take on PHPUnit vs SimpleTest please see this question:

[`What unit testing in php to start`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624093/what-unit-testing-in-php-to-start/4625909#4625909).

---

To sum that post up:

- PHPUnit is THE deFacto standard for Unit testing in PHP
- Simpletest is outdated and has (imho) outlifed it's usefulness.

### For Netbeans:

[`Netbeans as great PHPUnit Support`](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html)  and I've never seen or heard of anything like that for SimpleTest. I'm not even sure it can run tests written with SimpleTest at all. (At least i couldn't find anything)

So my clear recommendation is to got with phpunit as there are only upsides.

Comment: To install phpunit "easily" it requires you to run pear and on windows this can be a real headache.

Comment: Don't try it on windows! :D it's not a piece of cake, it's a piece of ... :D

Comment: @inf3rno There will be a phpunit at some point in time but so long there is "admin shell, pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/phpunit" and not having spaces in the php or pear install path

Comment: I need those spaces, sorry :D I don't want to kill my folder structure because phpunit uses DOS like pathes. :S Maybe I will not use phpunit, or I'll shorten the directory name containing space.