# Php SimpleTest CodeCoverage

Tags: php, simpletest

The test codes are written using SimpleTest framework, and I am looking for a tool or an open source solution to perform Code Coverage.

Comment: `phpunit` read about it, mostly used. https://phpunit.de/  in detail https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What unit testing in PHP to start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624093/what-unit-testing-in-php-to-start)

Answer (score 1):

Use SimpleTest's Coverage extension:

https://github.com/simpletest/simpletest/tree/master/extensions/coverage

Answer (score 0):

You can use **phpunit**

Read about it, mostly used.

http://phpunit.de -- page is in english

Git: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit

CodeCoverage: http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html